# Is there a Tumblr API for iOS?

Tags: ios, api, tumblr

I'd like to add simple Tumblr posting to my iOS app. Is there a drop-in API (preferably made directly by Tumblr) that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean like:  http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2 ???

Here is [the direct link to how to post a text posting](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#text-posts), which also shows what the JSON formatted responses should look like.

Comment: Something along the lines of facebook-ios-sdk, where I just drop the thing into my app and it handles login, posting, etc. I know there's an HTTP API for Tumblr.

Comment: Sounds like a business opportunity to me! (i.e. somebody writing a full blown drop-in SDK)  In any event, I also see a login (and dashboard) API at the bottom of that web page I linked to, earlier.

Comment: The API turns out to be so simple that all I really needed to do was build an ASIFormDataRequest.

Comment: /api/write doesn't seem to be there anymore.